# Heap Dump not working Centos 7

Tags: tomcat7, heap-memory, centos7, heap-dump

I have added following setting in my catalina.sh file
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/root/logs".

But still the heap dump file is not created when tomcat is going down. I have this setup on centos 7 on AWS.

Please help me in solving this issue... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest try create it manually if it is not generating automatically by using a JDK bundled tool called jmap, although we recommend that you use the automatic method above for best result.

For Linux/Solaris-based Operating Systems:
Please execute the following command on Linux OS:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <pid>
```

More Ref Follow the link below :

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/generating-a-heap-dump-219024032.html

Answer (score 0):

the tomcat process is usually set up to run as the tomcat user, who most likely will not have any write access to your /root folder.

Please try to set it to somewhere like /tmp